# Add Padding On Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it to where when a user is scrolling manually and reaches a certain class(in this example it is "content", that I add a top padding of 50px to a class named navigation.

This is what I have but it isn't working, any help is appreciated.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop >= document.getElementsByClassName("content").offsetTop) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navigation").style.paddingTop = "50px";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navigation").style.paddingTop = "0px";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like object, so you need to reference the index of the element you want to change when you use it. Or you can give those elements an `id` instead and use `getElementById()`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop >= document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].offsetTop) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0].style.paddingTop = "50px";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0].style.paddingTop = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 300vh;
}
.navigation {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="navigation">asdf</div>
</div>
```